# Display inline docs for custom property setter (ios, XCode 5.1.1)

Tags: ios, xcode, properties, documentation

In a `.h` file I have:

```
@property NSString *foo;

///@description foo sets greatness
-(void)setFoo:(NSString*)foo;
```

If I call in some `.m` `[myFooObject setFo...` it will show me the `foo sets greatness` description, but if I do `myFooObject.foo =...` it will not show me the description.

Is there any way to get it to display the description when calling the dot setter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was curious about this too, and Fred McCann's blog at DuckRowing.com finally [yielded a result](http://duckrowing.com/2010/03/18/documenting-objective-c-with-doxygen-part-i/):

```
/**
    the greatest property ever
*/
@property NSString *foo;
```

Output:

[image: Output]

---

As a side note, using the `@description` tag in this block operates in the exact same manner:

```
/**
    @description the greatest property ever
*/
@property NSString *foo;
```